# integration wih amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I want to use Amazon web services to store files, and I am new to Amazon web services. I want to know whether Amazon web services provides any API (e.g. web services) for us to upload, download, list files? Appreciate if anyone could provide some documents for a newbie.

Another question is, if I upload video files to Amazon web services, does it provide video streaming capability?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Are you looking to setup a web server, or just a file dump?  If just dumping/retrieving files, you may want to check out some sort of FTP/SFTP software.

Comment: Hi Brian, I just want to use Amazon web services because I heard it is cool and has a lot of CDN WW. Do you have any documents to refer to me, a newcomer. :-)

Comment: Actually this post caught my eye because I was looking to do some DIY web project this summer. :)

Comment: Good. Hopefully some day we can use your project, much cool thank what Amazon is doing, and free! :-)

Comment: Guy, from the questions you are asking, it appears to me that you didn't do any of the bare minimum of effort to find the answer. If that is the case, why would anyone answer your questions if you couldn't be bothered to do your share?

Comment: Bryan, isn't posting on Stack Overflow a good way to get a cooperative community to help with super basic to advanced questions?

Comment: Absolutely, and I'm not saying that asking a basic question is wrong--far from it. I'm saying that the way one asks a question is just as important: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before

Comment: @Brian, please note the first heading on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), **Do your homework**, followed by _Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?_ and _it saves us from reiterating obvious answers_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. I typed in "use amazon web services to store files" to Google and [the first link in the results](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#getting-started) led to the [web page you are looking for](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/).

Answer (score 3):

You can upload video files, to S3, simple storage service and u can make it to stream using CDN called cloud front. Google app engine doesn't allow to upload videos, even if it allows u need to store it as blob on google big data, which is complicated.

Yes aws provides API's to access your s3. Search for s3 documents, will get for things which will you a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend checking out the available options before deciding on one.  If you're looking to create a complete service from scratch, I would recommend Amazon Web Services.  If you wanted to give some of the control over to the service provider, but have use of a flurry of fairly good APIs, I'd recommend Google App Engine.  If you're looking for something along the Microsoft Stack, check out Azure!  [Windows Azure vs Amazon EC2 vs Google App Engine](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64727/windows-azure-vs-amazon-ec2-vs-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Webservice does have the capability to perform all actions as per your requirements. I would suggest you go through Amazon Simple Storage Service (commonly known as S3).
I would suggest you go through S3 FAQs to clarify your any specific questions around S3 which would be most likely answered there.

Amazon S3 is a really good choice for serving up video content.

> Note: Even though Amazon Webservice would have all the functionality
>   that you are looking for, kindly check the Pricing slab of the web
>   service.